# Functions do not output data after calling them

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

**Update:** the issue has been solved

Apparently, there is something wrong with spyder as I keep reordering the program's lines over and over again, and when I run the program, it works. When I run the program again it gives me a bunch of errors and sometimes the errors are illogical such as not defined variables. This led me to keep restarting the kernel, quitting IPython console, and reordering the lines too many times until the source code became messy and full of mistakes.

Simply, I solved the problem by accessing my data/ csv file first, and adding variables second. After that, I defined a function and called it at the end. Now, I am receiving the desired output.

Here is the final source code

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import csv
import random
import numpy as np
import random



#  Accessing our own data
# use this if you have data in your computer==>fin = pd.read_csv('/home/aziz/Desktop/b6h.csv')
# or just use the list below
fin = [1, -3, -2, 8, 4, -5, 6, -7] 

#  Obtaining our own data as floats in lines
#  DataIncomplete = (float(line) for line in fin['mv'])
DataIncomplete = (float(line) for line in fin)


#  This is to structure our data properly
positive = [n for n in DataIncomplete if n >= 0.0001]
data = pd.DataFrame(np.array(positive))

# Measures the length of the data after excluding the negative numbers
Total_Range_of_Data = len(data)

# Measures the number of samples needed for our filtered data
Total_Number_of_Needed_Samples = Total_Range_of_Data/200

# Convert floats to integers
FixedNumber = int(Total_Range_of_Data)

# Speciies the required range based on the FixedNumber
for x in range(1, FixedNumber):
    A_Random_Number = random.randint(1, int(Total_Number_of_Needed_Samples))
    A_Slice = A_Random_Number * 1
    StaEndSli = data[A_Slice:A_Slice + 200]
    FixedRange = int(Total_Number_of_Needed_Samples)

'''
Defining the function, looping the program based 
on the length of the data / 200 or any number of sample required
'''
def Grab(repeat):
        for repeat in range(FixedRange):
            print(StaEndSli)
Grab(FixedRange)
```

---

**There are mistakes and the code below does not work**

**The post has been updated one more time.
The code is now working and outputs a random slice of data. Yet, the loop function is still not working. When I type `print(StaEndSli)` the output does not differ as it is supposed to.
The previous source code has many lines in the wrong order so I removed it from the post as it is not beneficial at all**

I have written a source code to obtain slices from a CSV file randomly. The program uses for loop function to repeat the process over and over again according to the length of the variable   `Total_number_of_needed_samples`.
The problem is that the code runs without any error but it outputs nothing. I believe that there is something wrong with the order of lines.

here is the source code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import csv
import random
import numpy as np
import random


def Repeating(GrabingRandomSamples, Total_Number_of_Needed_Samples):
    for repeat in range(Total_Number_of_Needed_Samples):
        print(StaEndSli = data[A_Slice:A_Slice + 200])


    Repeating(GrabingRandomSamples)


    #  Accessing our own data
    #fin = pd.read_csv('/home/aziz/Desktop/b6h.csv')
    fin = [1, -3, -2, 8, 4, -5, 6, -7]


    #  Obtaining our own data as floats in lines
    DataIncomplete = (float(line) for line in fin)


    #  This is to structure our data properly
    positive = [n for n in DataIncomplete if n >= 0.0001]
    data = pd.DataFrame(np.array(positive))





    # Measures the length of the data after excluding the negative numbers
    Total_Range_of_Data = len(data)

    # Measures the number of samples needed for our filtered data
    Total_Number_of_Needed_Samples = Total_Range_of_Data/200
    FixedNumber = int(Total_Range_of_Data)

    for x in range(1, FixedNumber):
        A_Random_Number = random.randint(1, int(Total_Number_of_Needed_Samples))
        A_Slice = A_Random_Number * 1
        StaEndSli = data[A_Slice:A_Slice + 200]
        print(StaEndSli)

        Repeating( int(Total_Number_of_Needed_Samples))
print(StaEndSli)
```

I think the problem is in this specific part of the code since the most part of it is just bunch of working variables.

```
for x in range(1, FixedNumber):
    A_Random_Number = random.randint(1, int(Total_Number_of_Needed_Samples))
    A_Slice = A_Random_Number * 1
    StaEndSli = data[A_Slice:A_Slice + 200]
    print(StaEndSli)

    Repeating( int(Total_Number_of_Needed_Samples))
```

The idea of the program is that I want to access a CSV file with many instances. The program must do 3 things. 1- obtains positive numbers only. 2- slices consecutive instances randomly. 3- it loops the random slicing part, say, 30 times.. Or according according to the length of the `variable Total_number_of_needed_samples`.

Let's assume that we have 10000 instances. The program will slice a random sample with consecutive instances after excluding negative numbers as follows.

The data

```
 :
 :
 :
123
-123
658
98
-25
-654
-456
-354
  :
  :
```

The desired output after excluding the negative numbers

```
123
658
98
```

Then, the program will loop the function over and over again with other random samples.

Comment: Please provide the sample data and desired output.

Comment: The code that you show couldn't run without error. It accesses the variable `A_Random_Number` before giving it a value. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: The post has been updated with more details and example of the sample and desired output.

Comment: Your code doesn't run, and there is no easy way for anyone other than you to make your code run. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: The function seems to be calling itself recursively, with the wrong number of arguments. What is the line `Repeating(GrabbingRandomSamples)` inside of the definition of `Repeating` supposed to do?

Comment: @John Coleman I am trying to call the function so it finds another random slices.

Comment: The post has been updated again

Comment: You are defining `Repeating` so that it takes two parameters but are trying to call it with only 1. That makes no sense. The code that you show can't possibly run without error. Please take the effort of providing a [mcve] which other people can paste into a Python shell and directly see what the problem is.ok

Comment: Also: 1) `GrabingRandomSamples` is never used in the function and never defined in the calling code. What is the point of that variable? 2) What is the reason for the `1` in `A_Random_Number * 1` ? That makes little sense, beyond the fact that the first pass through that loop will throw an error because you haven't yet given `A_Random_Number` a value.

Comment: @JohnColeman _The A_Random_Number_ is just a variable specifies the beginning and end of a random slice. It later will be passed to another variable called _A_Slice_. By the way, I updated the post again and hopefully this matches the example given above.

Comment: The code as edited still won't work at all: 1) `print(StaEndSli = data[A_Slice:A_Slice + 200])` is at the top of the function, accessing the variables `data` and `A_Slice` before they are defined, and 2) the function `Repeating` is still defined as a function which takes 2 parameters (`GrabingRandomSamples` and `Total_Number_of_Needed_Samples`) but the function call `Repeating( int(Total_Number_of_Needed_Samples))` is trying to call it with 1. The code that you have provided still crashes rather than "runs without any error". Please only post code that you have tested.

Comment: @JohnColeman You are right. It worked in spyder at the beginning, but then it stopped working. Probably, I had to restart the kernel first. I have solved the issue now, and the code is working perfectly as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is something wrong with spyder as I keep reordering the program's lines over and over again, and when I run the program, it works. When I run the program again it gives me a bunch of errors and sometimes the errors are illogical such as not defined variables. This led me to keep restarting the kernel, quitting IPython console, and reordering the lines too many times until the source code became messy and full of mistakes.

Simply, I solved the problem by accessing my data/ csv file first, and adding variables second. After that, I defined a function and called it at the end. Now, I am receiving the desired output.

Here is the final source code

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import csv
import random
import numpy as np
import random



#  Accessing our own data
# use this if you have data in your computer==>fin = pd.read_csv('/home/aziz/Desktop/b6h.csv')
# or just use the list below
fin = [1, -3, -2, 8, 4, -5, 6, -7] 

#  Obtaining our own data as floats in lines
#  DataIncomplete = (float(line) for line in fin['mv'])
DataIncomplete = (float(line) for line in fin)


#  This is to structure our data properly
positive = [n for n in DataIncomplete if n >= 0.0001]
data = pd.DataFrame(np.array(positive))

# Measures the length of the data after excluding the negative numbers
Total_Range_of_Data = len(data)

# Measures the number of samples needed for our filtered data
Total_Number_of_Needed_Samples = Total_Range_of_Data/200

# Convert floats to integers
FixedNumber = int(Total_Range_of_Data)

# Speciies the required range based on the FixedNumber
for x in range(1, FixedNumber):
    A_Random_Number = random.randint(1, int(Total_Number_of_Needed_Samples))
    A_Slice = A_Random_Number * 1
    StaEndSli = data[A_Slice:A_Slice + 200]
    FixedRange = int(Total_Number_of_Needed_Samples)

'''
Defining the function, looping the program based 
on the length of the data / 200 or any number of sample required
'''
def Grab(repeat):
        for repeat in range(FixedRange):
            print(StaEndSli)
Grab(FixedRange)
```

Comment: The issue might be that you seem to be programming directly in the shell (as opposed to writing code in script files and *testing* it in the shell). The problem is unlikely to be spyder so much as how you are using it. There needs to be a clear separation between the code in your program and what you type in the interactive shell.